# What does the mmu line mean in zgc log?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, zgc

In a typical detailed zgc log, what's the meaning of these numbers in this mmu line?

`[gc,mmu      ] GC(18939) MMU: 2ms/0.0%, 5ms/0.0%, 10ms/0.0%, 20ms/0.0%, 50ms/36.2%, 100ms/68.0%`

I've searched and read several pages but still got no expression on that line, so I'm seeking answers here.

A sample of full output of a zgc cycle: (jdk version: 17)

```
[2022-12-26T20:09:49.485+0800][824756][gc,start    ] GC(18939) Garbage Collection (Allocation Rate)
[2022-12-26T20:09:49.485+0800][824756][gc,task     ] GC(18939) Using 8 workers
[2022-12-26T20:09:49.486+0800][824899][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Pause Mark Start 0.048ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.200+0800][824756][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Concurrent Mark 1713.889ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.200+0800][824899][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Pause Mark End 0.064ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.200+0800][824756][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Concurrent Mark Free 0.002ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.220+0800][824756][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Concurrent Process Non-Strong References 20.398ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.221+0800][824756][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Concurrent Reset Relocation Set 0.297ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.237+0800][824756][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Concurrent Select Relocation Set 16.689ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.238+0800][824899][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Pause Relocate Start 0.012ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,phases   ] GC(18939) Concurrent Relocate 9.731ms
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,load     ] GC(18939) Load: 17.62/16.95/16.43
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,mmu      ] GC(18939) MMU: 2ms/0.0%, 5ms/0.0%, 10ms/0.0%, 20ms/0.0%, 50ms/36.2%, 100ms/68.0%
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,marking  ] GC(18939) Mark: 8 stripe(s), 2 proactive flush(es), 1 terminate flush(es), 0 completion(s), 0 continuation(s)
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,marking  ] GC(18939) Mark Stack Usage: 32M
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,nmethod  ] GC(18939) NMethods: 33902 registered, 10715 unregistered
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,metaspace] GC(18939) Metaspace: 189M used, 191M committed, 1200M reserved
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,ref      ] GC(18939) Soft: 2612 encountered, 78 discovered, 0 enqueued
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,ref      ] GC(18939) Weak: 59639 encountered, 21677 discovered, 142 enqueued
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,ref      ] GC(18939) Final: 11628 encountered, 1203 discovered, 2 enqueued
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,ref      ] GC(18939) Phantom: 2517 encountered, 1758 discovered, 1 enqueued
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,reloc    ] GC(18939) Small Pages: 16920 / 33840M, Empty: 23428M, Relocated: 13M, In-Place: 0
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,reloc    ] GC(18939) Medium Pages: 9 / 288M, Empty: 192M, Relocated: 0M, In-Place: 0
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,reloc    ] GC(18939) Large Pages: 13 / 146M, Empty: 0M, Relocated: 0M, In-Place: 0
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,reloc    ] GC(18939) Forwarding Usage: 5M
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939) Min Capacity: 45056M(100%)
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939) Max Capacity: 45056M(100%)
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939) Soft Max Capacity: 45056M(100%)
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939)                Mark Start          Mark End        Relocate Start      Relocate End           High               Low
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939)  Capacity:    45056M (100%)      45056M (100%)      45056M (100%)      45056M (100%)      45056M (100%)      45056M (100%)
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939)      Free:    10782M (24%)        5440M (12%)       28954M (64%)       36920M (82%)       36922M (82%)        5376M (12%)
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939)      Used:    34274M (76%)       39616M (88%)       16102M (36%)        8136M (18%)       39680M (88%)        8134M (18%)
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939)      Live:         -              2504M (6%)         2504M (6%)         2504M (6%)             -                  -
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939) Allocated:         -              5342M (12%)        5448M (12%)        5487M (12%)            -                  -
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939)   Garbage:         -             31769M (71%)        8149M (18%)         143M (0%)             -                  -
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc,heap     ] GC(18939) Reclaimed:         -                  -             23620M (52%)       31625M (70%)            -                  -
[2022-12-26T20:09:51.248+0800][824756][gc          ] GC(18939) Garbage Collection (Allocation Rate) 34274M(76%)->8136M(18%)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term *MMU (Minimum Mutator Utilization)* was introduced in the [paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eguyb/papers/gc2001.pdf) "A Parallel, Real-Time Garbage Collector" by Perry Cheng and Guy E. Blelloch.

> The MMU allows one to see not just the maximum pause time, but the
> fraction of time that the processor is available to the mutator
> (application) for any time window of a specified size (worst case
> across the full execution). This is a much more useful measure of
> real-time capabilities than just the maximum pause time.

More formally, in HotSpot JVM

```
MMU(t) = (t - time_paused) / t
```

where `time_paused` is the total time when the application threads were paused during the last time slice of `t` milliseconds ending with the last GC pause.

E.g. `MMU 100ms/68.0%` means that during the last 100 milliseconds, application threads were running for the total duration of 68 milliseconds.

Comment: Many thanks for the explaining. (damn I missed the paper)

I also realized that the mmu line is always showing the worst case since the first gc.
That confused me for a while, as it is displayed in output of every cycle but statistics.